# Is the the spectral norm of a Boolean function bounded by the degree of its Fourier expansion?

Tags: co.combinatorics, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis

Let $f: \{-1,1\}^n \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ be a Boolean function.

The Fourier expansion of $f$ is
$$f(T) = \sum_{S \subseteq [n]} \widehat{f}(S)\ \chi_S(T)$$ 
where $\widehat{f}(S)$ are real numbers and $\chi_S(T)=\Pi_{i \in S} T_i$ is a parity function.

Let $d$ be the degree of the the Fourier expansion of $f$, i.e. 
$d= \max_{\widehat{f}(S)\neq 0} |S|$.

By Parseval's identity we have 
$$\sum_{S \subseteq [n]} \widehat{f}(S)^2=1$$

I am looking for a bound on
$$\sum_{S \subseteq [n]} |\widehat{f}(S)|$$

I think it is bounded by $d$.
But I have neither a proof nor a counterexample for this claim. Can someone provide a proof or give a counterexample?

Comment: atleast an idea is great for me

Comment: What is $d$?  For the Inner Product function that quantity is $2^{n/2}$, which is the largest possible value.

Comment: where $d$ is the degree of $f$ in the Fourier expansion of $f$. i.e., 
d= max {$|S| / \widehat{f}(S)$ $\neq 0$ }

Comment: for example $f: \{-1,1\}^3 \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$. $f=Majority$ 

then 

$f(x)= \frac{1}{2}x_1+\frac{1}{2}x_2+\frac{1}{2}x_3+\frac{1}{2}x_1x_2x_3$ 

Here degree of $f$ is $3$.

Comment: Inner product function has very large spectral norm, $2^{n/2}$, as Emanuele already said. The much more interesting question is to come up with Boolean functions with small spectral norm. For a characterization of Boolean functions of spectral norm $\leq M$, see the very nice paper by Green and Sanders (http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605524v2.pdf).

Comment: This quantity can be as large as $\sqrt{2^n}$ (as others point out), or as small as $1$ (e.g., any parity). Does that close the question?

Comment: @arnab: my understanding is that we are interested in the inverse question, i.e. given a Boolean function, is there some property of it that allows us to bound the spectral norm?

Comment: By using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality I got the upper bound $2^{n/2}$. My question is whether it is bounded by degree $d$ of the Fourier expansion of $f$. I had tried with many examples and for all of those I got  $\sum_{S \subseteq[n]} |\widehat{f}(S)| \leq d$, I am trying to prove this, but I have no idea.

Comment: $d$ is a number between $0$ and $n$, so obviously it can never be as large as $2^{n/2}$.

Comment: @Emanuele, could you please post your comment as an answer so the question becomes answered?

Comment: @EmanueleViola yes please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @arnab but we could give a bound in terms of $d$, right? For example, per Thm 4 [here](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/?p=535), degree $d$ boolean functions are $d2^{d-1}$ juntas, which implies roughly a $2^{d2^{d-2}}$ bound on the spectral norm. is this tight for small $d$? or did i misunderstand something?

Comment: @SashoNikolov: You are right. Bounding the spectral norm in terms of $d$ is an interesting question (though the questioner was asking if $d$ itself is a bound).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a standard fact that if $f:\{-,1,1\}^n \to \{-1,1\}$ is a function of Fourier degree $d$, then its Fourier coefficients are multiples of $2^{-d+1}$. In particular, every non-zero coefficient must be at least $2^{-d+1}$ in absolute value. Therefore, by Parseval, there are at most $2^{2(d-1)}$ non-zero coefficients, and so the spectral norm of $f$ is at most
$$\sum_{S}|\hat{f}(S)| \leq \sqrt{2^{2(d-1)}}\sqrt{\sum_{S}\hat{f}(S)^2} = 2^{d-1}$$.

This bound is tight. For example the complete binary decision tree of depth $d$ has spectral norm $2^{d-1}$. This can be shown, e.g., by induction on $d$.
The address function has also maximal possible spectral norm.

Answer (score 1):

For the Inner Product function that quantity is $2^{n/2}$, which is the largest possible value.

Comment: Is that easy to prove?

Comment: Are you asking why that is the largest possible value?  It follows by Cauchy Schwarz: $\sum_i a_i \cdot b_i \le \sqrt{\sum_i a_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_i b_i^2}$.  Let $b_i = 1$ and $a_i$ be the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the inner product function achieves the bound.