# Bound for the spectral norm of a boolean function

Tags: co.combinatorics, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis

As we know that the upper bound for the spectral norm of a Boolean function on $n$ variables is $2^{n/2}$. 
Is it possible to improve this bound..?

Can somebody provide me an example of a Boolean function whose spectral norm is more than the degree of the Fourier expansion of $f$

Comment: In the comments to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16730, you got an explicit example of a function whose spectral norm attains the bound $2^{n/2}$, and in particular is exponentially larger than the degree. Why do you not consider it to be an answer to your question, and why did you duplicate the question?

Comment: I am looking for some simpler example

Comment: I think as Emil said Emanuele's simple counterexample in his comment answers your question. Closing this one as a duplicate.